# Optionally applying .Where() to gorm.DB

Tags: pointers, go

I am new to Go and my pointer knowledge is rusty.  I want to mutate an instance of the gorm.DB so that I can apply 0 or more `Where` clauses to it.

```
func () {
    db := gorm.Open(/* ... */)
    err := applyWhere(db, filters).Order("created_datetime desc").Find(&rMessages).Error
    // ...
}

func applyWhere(db *gorm.DB, filters Filters) *gorm.DB {
    if filters.MessageType != "" {
        db = db.Where(&message{MessageType: string(filters.MessageType)})
    }
    return db
}
```

This seems not to work.  The db instance doesn't have the where applied.

*** edit 3 ***

This now works.  Not sure what the problem was before.  Please close / delete this question.

Comment: It has a lock because it needs a lock. I don't understand why you are trying to dereference the `*DB` returned from `Where`.

Comment: The pointer to the struct is important, especially if it contains a lock. You never want to copy a lock/mutex value, as it will break the locking logic. See [sync pkg](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) note: "Values containing the (sync) types defined in this package should _not_ be copied."

Comment: You don't need to assign the return value. They're creating what's called a "fluent API", basically the method returns its own receiver so that you can chain calls (query.Where().Order().Find()). If you're not chaining calls, you can ignore the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Yep I understand the you can chain calls.  I was trying to understand how you optionally apply a `.Where()`, order, limit, etc call.  Please see my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923332/assignment-copies-lock-value?noredirect=1#comment98523529_55924986

Comment: Btw I can't delete this question so have rewritten it substantially to focus on the first implementation I tried that failed.

Answer (score 2):

Read on how to do chaining with GORM properly here: [Method Chaining tutorial](http://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html). You take the `*gorm.DB` returned by one method and apply another method to it, that's it. You can also pass the `*gorm.DB` around, but be careful to only pass the pointer, not dereference it (otherwise you get the lock copy error as you found).

`Order`s are just another kind of query you can chain: http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Order

For example:

```
var p Product
db.Order("Price").Where("Price > 1000").First(&p)
```

So your `applyWhere` should just return `*gorm.DB` which you can further query

Comment: Yeah my first implementation was `func applyWhere (db *gorm.DB, filters Filters) *gorm.DB { ... }` but didn't work.  Not sure why.  I will try to go back to that implementation and figure out what was going wrong.  Thank you for the link to the tutorial, that's useful.